Help Me Identify This Sci-fi Movie about dapper robots trying to save humanity
Anyone remember a 60’s-70’s movie (British I think) where humanoid robots dressed in black suits, ties (and hats I think). It seems they came to protect humanity from itself. I think they interjected in situations of violence, but not sure. The had a synthesized voice (something like the German band Kraftwerk) saying something like “we are here, to preserve, humanity”. Been driving me crazy for years!

@Chenmunka if it matches that much, why don't answer it with proper explanation why you think so.

Yes, it is The Monitors (1969). Confirmed it on uTube. That was on my mind for some time! Thanks a bunch!

That sounds to me like The Monitors.  Here is a description from Rotten Tomatoes:

The extraterrestrial Monitors come to Earth hoping to save humanity
  from self-destruction by outlawing politics, violence, and sex.
  Humanity is not so happy about this, however, and a worldwide revolt
  soon follows in this science-fiction comedy, featuring members of the
  Second City comedy troupe.

The full movie is online on YouTube and other locations.
The most most memorable part of the film was the constant repetition of their chant, "The Monitors are your friends. Depend on the Monitors. Work for peace. Violence solves nothing. The Monitors bring peace. Peace brings happiness."

Yes, it is The Monitors (1969). Confirmed it on uTube. That was on my mind for some time! Thanks a bunch!
